# Find the length of a tangent line of a circle

Tags: geometry

> There are two circles with centers $O_1$, $O_2$ and radii $2$ and $8$ respectively. There is a common tangent at $M$. There is a common tangent line at $M_1$ of the first circle and $M_2$ of the second circle.

Please help me find the length of $M_1M_2$ and $m\angle M_1MM_2$.

I only found out that $m\angle M_1O_1M_2 = m\angle O_1M_2O_2$.

Comment: Think Pythagoras Theorem.

Comment: Draw the perpendicular from $O_2$ to the radius $O_1M_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the line from $O_1$ to $O_2$, and extend it beyond $O_1$.
Draw the line from $M_1$ to $M_2$, and extend it until it intersects $O_1O_2$.  lets call the point of intersection A.  Add in the radii from to the tangent points.

$\triangle O_1M_1A$ and $\triangle O_2M_2A$ are similar triangles.  And, $\angle O_1M_1A$ and $\angle O_2M_2A$ are right angles.

$O_1M_1$ is 1/4 as long as $O_2M_2$  So, $O_1A$ is 1/4 as long as $O_2A$.

That should give you enough information to get home.

For the angle.  Construct a line from $M$ to the Line $M_1M2$ that is perpendicular to $M_1M_2$ (and hence parallel to $O_1M_1$).  Lets call the point where these lines intersect $M'$.  We have now created one more similar triangle.  You should be able to find the length of $M_1M'$ and $O_1M'$ using the properties of similar triangles.  And the length of $M_1M$ using the Pythagorean theorem.  Use the same technique to find $M_2M$.  Finally use the law of cosines to find the measure of the angle.

If you haven't learned the law of cosines....
The Pythagorean theorem says,
$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ if angle $C$ is right.

The corollary is,
$a^2 + b^2 > c^2$ if angle $C$ is acute, and $a^2 + b^2 < c^2$ if angle $C$ is obtuse.  I can't get you more precise than that without the law of cosines.

Comment: Could you also help me find angel M1MM2?